# how to create models iteratively?

Tags: php, yii

as a beginner in Yii i have a question that I want to create models in iteration. For example I want to create result model for 30 students. How to create these models in iteration? I cant hardcode becaue number students may vary from class to class. 
In this approach i need to use tabular input but for that purpose i need to bind each model`s attribute to some element like

```
textArea
```

Definitive guide for yii presents this code

```
<div class="form">
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>
<table>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Count</th><th>Description</th></tr>
<?php foreach($items as $i=>$item): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($item,"[$i]name"); ?></td>
<td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($item,"[$i]price"); ?></td>
<td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($item,"[$i]count"); ?></td>
<td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextArea($item,"[$i]description"); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>

<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Save'); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
```

But how can i populate my array with distinct model names like model1,model2,model3 and so on, in iteration?
thanks 
EDIT:

```
public function actionCreate($exam=1,$class=1,$subject=4,$max=5,$min=4)
    {
                $students=  Student::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('class_grade_id'=>$class));
                //CVarDumper::Dump($students,100,true);
               // die();
                $i=0;
                $data=array();
        $model=new SubjectResult;
                foreach($students as $key)
                    {
                    $data[$i]=new SubjectResult();
                    $i++;
                    }
        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['SubjectResult']))
        {

            $model->attributes=$_POST['SubjectResult'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
                        'data'=>$data,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: each student have separate model?

Comment: yes, actually i have to create a model for result for say 30 students. not hardcoded but variable. Then i have to use these ,models in form

Comment: each student stored in different table? so you have 30 tables.? It's not good practice..

Comment: Not sure if you got your question right, but If you to generate model class for lot of tables automatically there is a extension called giic to do it automatically

Comment: @kumar, no i m not doing that, actually i have to enter the results of 30 students so i need to enter 30 records(one for each student). Now i want batch create.

Comment: Show you controller action code

Comment: are you doing edit 30 students in a single take itself?

Comment: please view my edit, i have used some dummy values for that attributes whose value is not required in form.

Comment: is this form related with update action? if so, then you should have added update code alone in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden field array to keep the ids.

```
<?php foreach($items as $i=>$item): ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($item,"[$i]name"); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::hiddenField('stud_ids[]' , $i);?>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($item,"[$i]price"); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($item,"[$i]count"); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextArea($item,"[$i]description"); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

In your update action,

```
$ids = $_POST["stud_ids"]
```

Pass this `$ids` to `foreach` to get each id and load model with id then update the records.